# MongoDB - вычисляемое условие

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Условная коллекция с документами:

```
{ _id: ObjectId(...), value: 19293 },
{ _id: ObjectId(...), value: 32123 }
```

Я хочу удалить все документы, где `value % 1000 == 123`, чтобы в коллекции осталось:

```
{ _id: ObjectId(...), value: 19293 }
```

Я знаю, как найти нужные документы с помощью `aggregate` -

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { filterValue: { $mod: ["$value", 1000] } } },
    { $match: { filterValue: 123 } }
])
```

После чего можно удалить найденное. Но меня инетерусует удалить нужные документы сразу в `db.test.deleteMany({ ??? })`, без предварительного поиска. Я ведь не могу сделать:

```
db.test.deleteMany({
    { $mod: ["$value", 1000] }: 123
})
```

Как правильно сделать это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать оператор [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/):

```
db.test.deleteMany({
    $expr: {
        $eq: [
            { $mod: ["$value", 1000] },
            123
        ]
    }
})
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122623/mongodb-calculated-condition-on-delete/67122791#67122791)